# how do i save the elements from forEach

Tags: node.js, arrays

how do i save the element from for each.
This code outputs the value to terminal how do I send it to **res.send** for postman.

```
            let cc = currencies.data.forEach(el => console.log(el.currency))
            let tz = timezones.default.forEach(el => console.log(el.label))
            res.status(200).send({
                status: true,
                status_code: 'SUCCESS',
                message: 'SUCCESS',
                currency: cc,
                timezones: tz,
            });
```

need to save el.currency and el.label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

1. Map the elements:

```
            let cc = currencies.data.map(el => el.currency)
            let tz = timezones.default.map(el => el.label)
```

2. Send them:

```
            res.status(200).send({
                status: true,
                status_code: 'SUCCESS',
                message: 'SUCCESS',
                currency: cc,
                timezones: tz,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mordor1110's answer is better — `forEach` doesn't return so you'd need an extra step like shown here. `map` does this by default so it's the right tool here. In JS sometimes you're iterating over collections that don't implement `map` (e.g. NodeList, which you get when you `querySelectorAll` something). In that case you have to resort to the "old" way (`map` is a more recent, ES6 addition to the language).

---

You could create an empty array before your first line and push to that in your loop

```
let cc = [];
let tz = [];
currencies.data.forEach(el => cc.push(el.currency))
timezones.default.forEach(el => tz.push(el.label))
res.status(200).send({
  status: true,
  status_code: 'SUCCESS',
  message: 'SUCCESS',
  currency: cc,
  timezones: tz,
});

console.log(cc, tz);
```